# Is Kenny Ratzon a Kohen?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Each time the chazzan recites a verse from *Birkat Kohanim* near the end of *Chazarat Hashat"z*, I hear the congregation yelling "Kenny Ratzon". Who is he? Is he a Kohen?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).